# Android Studio: How to change the file path to the .apk file after moving the entire project?

Tags: path, android-studio-2.1

When I try to build my Android Studio project, it gives me the following dialog box (see link). (Clicking OK does not fix the problem and the same dialog comes up again.)

[image]

I realize that this directory is the one I just moved the entire project from (I just dragged and dropped the folder in finder). But now it's looking for this file (slice_2.apk) in the wrong location, because its path should now be:

Users/cssummer17/YelpMeImTrying/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_2.apk

instead of

Users/cssummer17/**ud851-Exercises/Lesson02-GitHub-Repo-Search**/YelpMeImTrying/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_2.apk

I would like to change where it's looking for the file, but I'm not sure how to change this. I have not changed any of my build.gradle files, and none of them have any relevant file paths in them, except one that contains the sdk location (which has not moved).

Thank you very much!

EDIT: I'm also pretty sure this is an issue with Instant Run, because apparently slice files do have something to do with Instant Run. After disabling it, everything seems to run fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to disable the instant run, try to clean the project:

1. Select the option "Clean project" in the "Build" menu
2. Then close and re-open Android Studio

This worked for me

Comment: I can't say whether this worked or not, as I decided to pivot away from Android development entirely and no longer have the relevant files, but thank you for your answer!

Comment: This 100% solved the problem I'd been having. Didn't know the clean option was there. Thanks.

Comment: Had same issue with Android Studio 3.4.1, but this solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"Build" -> "Rebuild Project", then "Run" again.

Helped me on the same problem when I copied my project to another PC (AndroidStudio 3.2.1 OS Windows)

Comment: I no longer have the relevant files for this project, so I can't say if this worked for me, but thanks for the answer!